# A Mysql Query from joomla is taking very long time

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Sorry for this Question. I am not a Good Programmer

[Everything](http://www.yn47.com/m/400001/eyes-1x01-episodio-pilota-ita-satrip-xvid-sid.html) Executed well with few menu items. but with 14K menu items. i stuck with this query. This is happening when i try to access

`administrator/index.php?option=com_modules&view=module&layout=edit&id=97`
Is there any way to alter the query ??

Query

```
SELECT a.id    AS value, 
       a.title AS text, 
       a.alias, 
       a.level, 
       a.menutype, 
       a.type, 
       a.template_style_id, 
       a.checked_out 
FROM   gjb0e_menu AS a 
       LEFT JOIN `gjb0e_menu` AS b 
              ON a.lft > b.lft 
                 AND a.rgt < b.rgt 
WHERE  a.published != -2 
GROUP  BY a.id, 
          a.title, 
          a.alias, 
          a.level, 
          a.menutype, 
          a.type, 
          a.template_style_id, 
          a.checked_out, 
          a.lft 
ORDER  BY a.lft ASC
```

Php code

```
require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_menus/helpers/menus.php'; 
$menuTypes = MenusHelper::getMenuLinks();
```

---

```
        <ul class="treeselect">
            <?php foreach ($menuTypes as &$type) : ?>
            <?php if (count($type->links)) : ?>
                <?php $prevlevel = 0; ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="treeselect-item pull-left">
                        <label class="pull-left nav-header"><?php echo $type->title; ?></label></div>
                <?php foreach ($type->links as $i => $link) : ?>
                    <?php
                    if ($prevlevel < $link->level)
                    {
                        echo '<ul class="treeselect-sub">';
                    } elseif ($prevlevel > $link->level)
                    {
                        echo str_repeat('</li></ul>', $prevlevel - $link->level);
                    } else {
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                    $selected = 0;
                    if ($this->item->assignment == 0)
                    {
                        $selected = 1;
                    } elseif ($this->item->assignment < 0)
                    {
                        $selected = in_array(-$link->value, $this->item->assigned);
                    } elseif ($this->item->assignment > 0)
                    {
                        $selected = in_array($link->value, $this->item->assigned);
                    }
                    ?>
                        <li>
                            <div class="treeselect-item pull-left">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left" name="jform[assigned][]" id="<?php echo $id . $link->value; ?>" value="<?php echo (int) $link->value; ?>"<?php echo $selected ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                                <label for="<?php echo $id . $link->value; ?>" class="pull-left"><?php echo $link->text; ?> <span class="small"><?php echo JText::sprintf('JGLOBAL_LIST_ALIAS', $this->escape($link->alias));?></span></label>
                            </div>
                    <?php

                    if (!isset($type->links[$i + 1]))
                    {
                        echo str_repeat('</li></ul>', $link->level);
                    }
                    $prevlevel = $link->level;
                    ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

---

Here is the function which creates the Query.

```
public static function getMenuLinks($menuType = null, $parentId = 0, $mode = 0, $published = array(), $languages = array())
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('a.id AS value, a.title AS text, a.alias, a.level, a.menutype, a.type, a.template_style_id, a.checked_out')
        ->from('#__menu AS a')
        ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__menu') . ' AS b ON a.lft > b.lft AND a.rgt < b.rgt');

    // Filter by the type
    if ($menuType)
    {
        $query->where('(a.menutype = ' . $db->quote($menuType) . ' OR a.parent_id = 0)');
    }

    if ($parentId)
    {
        if ($mode == 2)
        {
            // Prevent the parent and children from showing.
            $query->join('LEFT', '#__menu AS p ON p.id = ' . (int) $parentId)
                ->where('(a.lft <= p.lft OR a.rgt >= p.rgt)');
        }
    }

    if (!empty($languages))
    {
        if (is_array($languages))
        {
            $languages = '(' . implode(',', array_map(array($db, 'quote'), $languages)) . ')';
        }

        $query->where('a.language IN ' . $languages);
    }

    if (!empty($published))
    {
        if (is_array($published))
        {
            $published = '(' . implode(',', $published) . ')';
        }

        $query->where('a.published IN ' . $published);
    }

    $query->where('a.published != -2')
        ->group('a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.level, a.menutype, a.type, a.template_style_id, a.checked_out, a.lft')
        ->order('a.lft ASC');

    // Get the options.
    $db->setQuery($query);

    try
    {
        $links = $db->loadObjectList();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException $e)
    {
        JError::raiseWarning(500, $e->getMessage());

        return false;
    }

    if (empty($menuType))
    {
        // If the menutype is empty, group the items by menutype.
        $query->clear()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('#__menu_types')
            ->where('menutype <> ' . $db->quote(''))
            ->order('title, menutype');
        $db->setQuery($query);

        try
        {
            $menuTypes = $db->loadObjectList();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException $e)
        {
            JError::raiseWarning(500, $e->getMessage());

            return false;
        }

        // Create a reverse lookup and aggregate the links.
        $rlu = array();

        foreach ($menuTypes as &$type)
        {
            $rlu[$type->menutype] = & $type;
            $type->links = array();
        }

        // Loop through the list of menu links.
        foreach ($links as &$link)
        {
            if (isset($rlu[$link->menutype]))
            {
                $rlu[$link->menutype]->links[] = & $link;

                // Cleanup garbage.
                unset($link->menutype);
            }
        }

        return $menuTypes;
    }
    else
    {
        return $links;
    }
```

Comment: add explain and post that along with the schema

Comment: That left join with > and < is going to be extremely slow. We really don't know what's in youe data or what you're trying to do, but you've got to simplify that join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the join. I'm pretty sure the join has absolutely no effect in your query, and it will be a lot quicker. You can try to run the query directly in your database with and without the join, to verify that the result is the same.

I'm not sure what this join was intended to do, but i guess it is some remnant of some functionality the programmer was trying to achieve, but that was realized differently or dropped, leaving a useless join.

The structure of this kind of hierarchical table is like this to prevent these sort of join. You have a lft and a rgt value, and any item that is between the lft and the rgt is a sub-item. In addition you have a level-value, telling you how deep in the tree a value is. So to select all children of an item, you can do:

```
select * where lft>item.lft and rgt>item.rgt
```

To select only direct descendants of your item, do

```
select * where lft>item.lft and rgt>item.rgt and level=item.level+1
```

The structure in the database is a little hard to maintain, requiring special functions to update the data, but it is quick to search and extract data.

So, your getMenuLinks() - function should start like

```
public static function getMenuLinks($menuType = null, $parentId = 0,
  $mode = 0, $published = array(), $languages = array())
{
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('a.id AS value, a.title AS text, a.alias, a.level,
      a.menutype, a.type, a.template_style_id, a.checked_out')
    ->from('#__menu AS a');

  // Filter by the type
  if ($menuType) 
  ...
```